# Phpfox::getService('user.process')->add($aVals)

Tags: php, mysql, phpfox

I want insert some record via external PHP  script in phpfox framework table `phpfox_user`

Applied [reference](https://store.phpfox.com/kb/article/504/accessing-php-library-functions-from-outside-of-phpfox).The registration of user in table phpfox_user accessing php library functions from outside of phpfox was working fine previously.

`$iId = Phpfox::getService('user.process')->add($aVals);`

```
// if fine, $iId is ID of user in `phpfox_user` table, otherwise $iId = false.


<?php
echo "This is the beginning."; 
include('auth.php');
include('config1.php');
define('PHPFOX', true); 
define('PHPFOX_DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
define('PHPFOX_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . PHPFOX_DS); 
define('PHPFOX_START_TIME', array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()))); 
require_once(PHPFOX_DIR . 'include' . PHPFOX_DS . 'init.inc.php'); 


    $aVals = array(
'full_name' => 'Naveen Kumart',
'email' => 'testrew@abc.com',
'password' => 'Alobha1',
'gender' => 1, // 1: male 2: female
);

if (Phpfox::getParam('core.registration_enable_dob')) {
// if birthday on registration is required, assign birthday parameters here. I give a sample 1/1/1988
$aVals['month'] = '1'; 
$aVals['day'] = '1';
$aVals['year'] = '1988';


}

$iId = Phpfox::getService('user.process')->add($aVals);

// if fine, $iId is ID of user in `phpfox_user` table, otherwise $iId = false.
if ($iId) {
echo $iId;
} else {
echo 'false';
}

echo "This is the end"; 


?>
```

Comment: What the problem are there warnings or errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpFox V4, you replace:

```
<?php
echo "This is the beginning."; 
include('auth.php');
include('config1.php');
define('PHPFOX', true); 
define('PHPFOX_DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
define('PHPFOX_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . PHPFOX_DS); 
define('PHPFOX_START_TIME', array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()))); 
require_once(PHPFOX_DIR . 'include' . PHPFOX_DS . 'init.inc.php');
```

By

```
define('PHPFOX_PARENT_DIR', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PHPFOX_NO_RUN', true);
require('./PF.Base/start.php');
```

Update `PHPFOX_PARENT_DIR` if your file is not the same dir with index.php

Comment: Thanks for information, I am using the version- Core Version: 3.7.6beta1(build 1)
PHP Version:
5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: I am using the PHPFox version - 3.7.6

Comment: Can you please post add($aVals) function from user module service. As I am not near my development machine